# Creating an share app extension for YouTube app, non-native share menu?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ios-app-extension

I'm creating an app extension so I can share a video url from the YouTube app share menu, this is working just fine on an iPhone I've been testing, however when I tried the same on an iPad mini, the share menu seems to be different, and instead of having the native one, seems like the tablet version has a custom one, not being possible to add my own app to it.

So, this raises the question, is this intended?, do I have to config something different for this non-native kind of menu?, or should I do something different using the YouTube API?.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the APIs you are using and how you are using them? Samples of code working on iPhone and not on a iPad would also be helpful.

Comment: Actually the issue is not with my code or lack of it, but with the share menu o the youTube app itself, seems like at least for iPad (maybe the OS has something to do?) the share menu is not native, but a custom made, which makes impossible to use with an app extension.